# Ruby "-" to - or "+" to +

Tags: ruby

I have this simple question actually but I can't find the correct answer.
I would like to know how i could do something like this:

```
    direction="-"
    value=17
    movement = direction value
```

so that it would give me: movement=-17
I know i could use an if statement but I was wordering if there is a quicker way for converting "-" to simply -

Comment: Does `direction` have to be a string? You could use `-1` and multiply that with `value`.

Comment: what are the possible values of directio? is always unary?

Comment: I think having `direction` be +1 or -1 makes more sense, that way you can just multiply it with value as @waldrumpus points out.

Comment: I like how that kind of question can lead to very creative solutions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution from my side

```
direction = "-"
value = 17
movement = (direction + value.to_s).to_i
```

It is very basic, not using anything complex, which might make it a bit unclean, but at least demonstrates that knowing just the very basic operations in ruby you can solve many tasks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send)

```
movement = 0.send(direction.to_sym, value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unary operators internally use a trailing `@`, so:

```
direction = "-"
value = 17
movement = value.send(direction + "@")
#=> -17
```

That said, IMO this is unnecessarily convoluted and a simple conditional expression (using `?`) would be better.

Comment: I'd probably use `value.send("#{direction}@").

Answer (score 1):

Just set the direction to -1 or +1, so you can multiply with this value:

```
direction = -1
value = 17
movement = direction * value
```

The result will be -17.

If you set the direction to 1, the result will be 17. Therefore, you can use both directions, depending on your direction value.

Answer (score 0):

No 'if' in this solution:

```
movement = (direction == "-") ? -value : value
```

Comment: this was kind of tongue-in-cheek, there is no litteral `if` in my solution.